# How to clone Windows 7 Profile to another computer? (ALL jumplists, icons, passwords)

Tags: windows, jumplist

I used Macrium Reflect Free to make a backup after my Windows had BSOD (did the all the repairs avail to no avail)

I did a offline image copy of my old hard drive with Macrium.

Im able to login with my User profile fine but  (exact same hardware)

Where are the passwords saved? They are not C:\Users(Username)
Specifically my outlook,

When i launched chrome, it asked me to resign in.

Some icons from the taskbar where missing
Wordpad was there, but no Jumplist .
Notepad was there, but with jumplist
windows Media player there, in taskbar, but no jumplist.
All chrome profile icons gone.

Any help would be appreciated.